# Way to declare float compile-time constant in C

Tags: c, floating-point, compile-time-constant

I know that I can declare a named compile-time constant in C for integers by using enums, but is there a way to declare named compile-time constants in C for floats as well, without using macros (I know that C++ has constexpr, but I am strictly using C right now)? Answers containing compiler-specific C-language extensions are also greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the context that requires you to have a compile time constant float?

Comment: @user2079303 I like making sure that my constant variables are being compiled to immediates.

Comment: Don't you think your compiler will know how to do the right thing? Any examples of where it breaks badly?

Comment: There's no floating point equivalent of `enum`

Comment: You’ll need to use a macro in C.

Comment: @Cppplus1 "making sure that my constant variables are being compiled to immediates." is interesting.  Why is this important for your code?

Comment: @chux Performance, since if declaring a floating-point compile time constant is possible, why not just ensure that the floating-point numbers are compiled to the fastest instruction mode?

Comment: @Cppplus1 "why not just ensure that they are constants and compiled to immediates?"  --> because that might not be the fastest.  IAC, `123.456`, `1e10`, `0x1.2Ap21` are 3 examples of _floating-constants_.  How are those _floating-constants_ of that form not sufficient for your C code?

Comment: @chux OP is asking for named constants...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Fair enough.  Perhaps a better question would be what is insufficient about using `#define` like `#define MY_PI 3.14`  `#define MY_C ((double){ 299792458.0 })`?

Comment: (a) What you are asking for—declaring constants—is not want you want—fast code or small code. The compiler makes its own decisions about whether to use immediates, to load constants from a read-only data page, to calculate constants on the fly, to fold constants into larger expressions, or other options. (b) You can declare constants with `static const float foo = value;`. (c) What you want is likely not helpful; the time it takes to load constants is almost certainly not what is slowing your code significantly.

Comment: Since you mentioned Compiler Specific also OK. This kinda makes it that OK too, check something called Type Punning, I think this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Use array of const float.
Which will produce constant data of type float.
`const float *arr[3] = {11.21,21.31,31.23}`